# Installing Novell iPrint Client on Ubuntu

Tags: printing

My organisation has a shared printer, which operates through the [Novell Micro Focus iPrint client](https://www.novell.com/products/iprint/download/). Yet, this seems to be only available for SUSE Linux. I've tried to use the Windows version by running the Windows installer via Wine, but it does not work.

How can I get access to the printer in my Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Novell provides a `.rpm` file for SUSE Linux. We can use this in Ubuntu too.

- First, download the latest `.rpm` file. As of December 2016, this corresponds to SUSE 11. **Notice that the file is provided by Novell to your organisation, as it is closed-source, commercial software**. Ask your IT manager in case you cannot get access to it.
- We need to convert it to a `.deb` file. For this, install `alien` and then convert:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install alien
  sudo alien -d --scripts /path/to/novell-iprint-xclient.x86_64.rpm
  ```

  The name of the file might be different for you. This creates in your home folder a `.deb` file, called something like `novell-iprint-xclient-sl_6.503.20111114-7.5_amd64.deb`
- Install as usual:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i novell-iprint-xclient-sl_6.503.20111114-7.5_amd64.deb
  ```
- Now, we need to run some scripts, that help configure the program (environment variables, etc):

  ```
  . /opt/novell/iprint/bin/iprint-gnome-init
  . /etc/profile.d/novell-iprint.sh
  ```
- If your user is not on the printing group, it might be necessary to add it:

  ```
  sudo usermod -aG lpadmin <username>
  ```
- Now, you need to add the network printer in order for the client to detect it. For this, you need the `ipp` address of the printer, give to you by the IT team. It should look something like this:

  ```
  ipp://iprint.myorganisation.domain/ipp/printer_name
  ```

  With this information, we can add it to the Client. From a terminal, type:

  ```
  iprntcmd --addprinter ipp://iprint.myorganisation.domain/ipp/printer_name
  ```

  This should add it successfully. You can see it active in the Client icon which automatically appeared after installing the Client:

[image]

- Finally, to print, just select the printer when printing from a program (for example, evince), or use the command line:

  ```
  iprntcmd --printfile ipp://iprint.myorganisation.domain/ipp/printer_name /path/to/file/to/print
  ```

  (or use `-p` instead of `--printfile`).

  More information about `iprntcmd` can be found in the [Novell manual](http://www.novell.com/documentation/oes11/iprint_lx/data/b1914lx6.html), which was also installed locally (`man iprntcmn`).

---

Sources: [this (obsolete) post](https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/using-iprint-with-ubuntu/) plus my own installation attempts.